# What is the name of the function that causes a page to rise above another when scrolling?

Tags: gui-design, scrolling, javascript

What is the name of the function used on websites to make your second page appear to rise above the first and where may I find this particular plugin?

I understand that this is jquery functionality yet do not understand where to look or start coding.

You will find an example at the following:

http://www.datadrivenlondon.com/

Comment: [parallax scrolling?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)

Comment: that would be it

Comment: Already asked on SO. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/16083329/979621 for examples and how-to-implement details.

Comment: Already answered elsewhere and in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be parallax animation.

Comment: Now that you know, don't do it. Please?